# How to manage threads in multithreaded application that opens 160 windows in four monitors

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, concurrency, .net-4.6.1

I have a Windows Forms application which uses around 200 threads and 160 of them are Forms threads.

I am gathering data into application with TCP connection, I enqueue the messages into many `ConcurrentQueue<T>`s with a single thread. 40 other threads lets call them readerThreads are checking if there is any item in their queue and dequeue the message, and process into forms. Form threads processes their own queues and show the data.

One readerThread(threadA) in particular is processing the 90% of the messages from his `concurrentQueue(queueA)`. So when live data starts to accumulate so fast, `queueA` is swelled up and Application is starting to lag.

So I want to give `queueA` a higher priority than others, and also I think I am losing so much time while OS changes between the threads so I want to let threadA run with everything OS can offer while queueA is getting dequeued. Currently I am using `new Thread();` for every thread and not using any thread pool. I know it is not wise and want to change it to something better.

Firstly, can using `ThreadPriority.Highest` on `threadA` help me at this issue and secondly, what can you offer instead of using `new Thread();`. Any example would be very helpful.

Comment: Instead of `new Thread()` take a look at Microsoft's recommended `Task` library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model It may help manage the async tasks better.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: *"are checking if there is any item"* -- Do you have busy loops that are continuously trying to dequeue items from the `ConcurrentQueue`s? Or you have a `Thread.Sleep(X)` in the loops?

Comment: I use autoResetEvent.WaitOne(500); after checking the queue in every thread and autoResetEvent is Set() if any messages are enqueued

Comment: *"dequeue the message, and process into forms."* -- Could you elaborate on this? What kind of processing is involved for each message? For example does it involve reading or persisting data in a database, or updating UI controls in a `Form`?

Comment: queueA.Dequeue(out message);

foreach form: form(i)UpdateQueue.Enqueue(message);

-in form thread-

when(tmrUpdatetick)
{
  while(form1UpdateQueue.TryDequeue(out message))
  {
   form1BindingSource.Add(message);
  }
}
Also for clarification my application is used by 4x 24 inch monitors, 32 gb RAM and 16 cores(32 logical processor). Application uses around of 16 gb Ram at the end of the day when the whole daily data accumulates. There is no problem if the data is at the daily avarage, but when the continuous data is wild, application is not very user friendly until it gets chill

Comment: You really do need to transform this into a fully `async` implementation. You could do this with maybe 8 threads (or however many processors you have) using the thread pool. All you need to do is queue tasks on the threadpool, and then marshal them back to a single UI thread for display. `BindingSource` is another bugbear: it's very nice if you only have one of them, but they are slow and 160 of them is going to be awful.

Comment: The only advice that I can offer, given the limited info provided, is to look at the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class, and the [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) from the TPL Dataflow library. Both are better than messing around with `ConcurrentQueue`s and `AutoResetEvent`s.

Answer (score 0):

> 160 of them are Forms threads

Assuming you mean *UI threads*, that just sounds insane. Normally there should be only one UI thread. There might be some special cases where more are warranted, but 160? Do you have 160 windows that display data?

I would assume your readers work something like

1. Fetch data from queue
2. Process data
3. Update UI

If this is not keeping up you need to find out **why**, not just try to hide the problem by playing around with more threads. Start with a profiler, if the processing is slow, see if it can be optimized, or move it to one or more *background* threads. If the UI updates take to much time, see if you can reduce the frequency of UI updates, or reduce the complexity of the UI, possibly using custom rendering to get better control of what is rendered.

While using "new Thread()" most likely do not help, there is no telling if it is the actual problem. So you should always start by *measuring*, not changing things blindly in the hope that it helps.

Comment: For clarification my application is used by 4x 24 inch monitors, 32 gb RAM and 16 cores(32 logical processor). Application uses around of 16 gb Ram at the end of the day when the whole daily data accumulates. There is no problem if the data is at the daily avarage, but when the continuous data is wild, application is not very user friendly until it gets chill

Comment: @EminSahingoz Does that in any way motivate *160 ui threads*?

Comment: It is desired to have 160 different windows forms where all of them works independently. My desire is to handle these form threads the way it should be handled with .Net features

Comment: @EminSahingoz While is is perfectly possible that the amount of threads causes excessive task switching. **You need to profile your code to find out why it is slow**. You have not presented any reason to expect that just switching to the threadpool would do much of anything.

Comment: Like others, I'm astounded that you are using 160 UI threads in a Windows Forms application.  Does this mean you have 160 Windows Forms main forms, each running on a different thread?  Wow.  Generally, when I write a Windows forms app, I have one UI thread and possibly many background (or threadpool pooled) threads.  I'm surprised you got this working

Comment: My actual hint was that users, stated that at the abnormal data flow, some of their forms started glitching(disappearing complately and showing again). Sory to bother you with lack of proof since the project is huge and the Application is gathering data from 7 different executables with TCP connection. It is hard to create a test case and it will solely take 3 month of my time to provide a solid test enviroment. On top of that I need better equipment to profile such application since App is almost using half of my RAM and most profilers use as much ram as App does.Thanks for your time & advice

Answer (score 0):

### Windows and Wndprocs

A little background on how win32 works underneath the C# WinForms veneer. When a process starts, it's main thread registers a window with a window procedure or wndproc, tell Windows to create the window, and then goes into a loop waiting for Windows to give it messages to dispatch to its wndprocs.

This can be seen in the C++ code below:

```
const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

WNDCLASS wc = { };

wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);

// Create the window.

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
    L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

    // Size and position
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,       // Parent window    
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    NULL        // Additional application data
    );

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

// Run the message loop.

MSG msg = { };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program

Creating 160 windows is simply a matter of registering at most 160 window classes and calling `CreateWindowEx` 160 times. You only need one thread to handle pumping the messages from the OS and dispatching them to the different wndprocs.

Using C# doesn't change the fact that this is still happening under the hood. You still only need 1 thread to manage the messages from the OS. Having a thread per window will only cause context thrashing.

### Updating 160 windows

Let's say the OS wants to send 1 message to each window.

#### 160 threads for 160 windows

In this case the OS:

1. Puts 1 message in queue for 1 thread
2. Switches context and control over to the 1 thread
3. Said thread gets the message, dispatches it to the wndproc
4. Wndproc handles the message
5. Thread asks for the next message and is put to sleep
6. OS repeats steps 159 more times

Each time the OS and the threads transfer control back and forth, there is a cost incurred as the OS saves the state of the thread, schedules the next thread, and loads the state of the next thread.

#### 1 thread for 160 windows

Consider the alternative:

1. The os puts 160 messages in queue for the main thread
2. Switches context and control over to the main thread
3. Main thread gets the message, and dispatches it to the proper wndproc
4. Wndproc handles the message
5. Thread repeats 159 times
6. Thread sleeps

In this case, context switching is minimized.